# Why do I appear to have an infinite loop?

Tags: python, while-loop, infinite-loop, python-2.x

This is part of a tutorial. My goal was to take an input from user and then increment it while a condition is true.

```
inputNum = raw_input("What is max number?")

def incrementF(greatest):
    i = 0
    numbers = []

    while i < greatest:
        print "At the top of the list numbers is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i += 1
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom i is %d" % i

    print "The numbers:"

    for num in numbers:
        print num

incrementF(inputNum)
```

When I run the script and type anything in for inputNum, rather than a few lines of output, I appear to run into an infinite loop.

For example, is the raw input prompt gave 10, I'd have expected to see something like:

> ```
> At the top of the list numbers is 0,
> Numbers now: 0,
> 0
> At the top of the list numbers is 1,
> Numbers now: 1,
> 1
> ```

I've read over my script several times and cannot see. I suspect it could have something to do with indenting? But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As quoted in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) for `raw_input`:

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string
>   (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

So, `greatest` will be a string because you used `raw_input` to get it.

Furthermore, in Python 2.x, strings are always evaluated as being greater than integers*:

```
>>> 1 < 'a'
True
>>> 100000000000 < 'a'
True
>>>
```

This means that the condition of your while-loop will always evaluate to `True` because `greatest` will always be evaluated as being greater than `i`.  Thus, you get an infinite loop.

You can fix this problem simply by making `greatest` an integer like `i`:

```
inputNum = int(raw_input("What is max number?"))
```

---

*Note: If you would like some more information on this, see [How does Python compare string and int?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int)

Comment: Does `string < int` always return non-`False`?

Comment: Damn, that's quick. +1.

Comment: @zneak Yes. However, note that this behavior is fixed in Python 3, comparing int to string will raise a `TypeError`.

Comment: Now it's +5 dammmmmmmmn

Comment: Thanks! Works now, accepting shortly. Will remember that raw_inputs are strings from now on.

Comment: Actually, to add to my last comment... Why did it behave that way, even if it was a string? I'll research it

Comment: @DougFirr - See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270680/how-does-python-compare-string-and-int).  Also, as aIKid said, this behavior is fixed in Python 3.x.

Comment: Ah, I see my follow up question on why was answered by zneak above